# Client/Server file transfer using CipherOutputStream

Tags: java, serversocket, encryption

Trying to write a client/server program where the client reads a text file and sends it to the server sockect using CipherOutputStream.
The expected text file is created but empty and I the following error

> Read Length-1
>
> EOF:null

I have this method **encrypt()** that does the encrytion and then sends the out the data

```
private static void encrypt(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {

    try {

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
```

// bytes at this stream are first encoded

```
        os = new CipherOutputStream(os, ecipher);
```

// read in the clear text and write to out to encrypt

```
        int numRead = 0;

        while ((numRead = is.read(buf)) >= 0) {

            os.write(buf, 0, numRead);

        }
```

// close all streams

```
        os.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println("I/O Error:" + e.getMessage());

    }

}
```

Below is most of the code at the client end

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    //Handle open button action.
    if (e.getSource() == openButton) {
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(FileChooserDemo.this);

        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            try {
                SecretKey key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();

                AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

                ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

                dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

                ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);

                dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);

                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();

                Socket s = null;
                s = new Socket("localhost", 6880);
                DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());


                encrypt(new FileInputStream(file), output);

                log.append("encrypted " + newline);

                log.append("Sent" + file.getName() + "." + newline);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FileChooserDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } else {
            log.append("Open command cancelled by user." + newline);
        }
        log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());

        //Handle save button action.
    } else if (e.getSource() == saveButton) {
        int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(FileChooserDemo.this);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            //This is where a real application would save the file.
            log.append("Saving: " + file.getName() + "." + newline);
        } else {
            log.append("Save command cancelled by user." + newline);
        }
        log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());
    }
}
```

And then the listening server reads in the data using CipherInputStream and then writes that to a text file.
The server contains the following

```
private static void decrypt(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {

    try {

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
```

// bytes read from stream will be decrypted

```
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(is, dcipher);
```

// read in the decrypted bytes and write the clear text to out

```
        int numRead = 0;

        while ((numRead = cis.read(buf)) >= 0) {

            os.write(buf, 0, numRead);

        }
```

// close all streams

```
        cis.close();

        is.close();

        os.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println("I/O Error:" + e.getMessage());

    }

}

public void run() {
    try {

        SecretKey key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();

        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);


        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);

        decrypt(input, new FileOutputStream("cleartext-reversed.txt"));

        FileWriter out = new FileWriter("test.txt");
        BufferedWriter bufWriter = new BufferedWriter(out);


        System.out.println("receive from : "
                + clientSocket.getInetAddress() + ":"
                + clientSocket.getPort());
        //Step 1 read length
        int nb = input.read();
        System.out.println("Read Length" + nb);

        String enctext = Character.toString(input.readChar());
        Integer.toString(nb);
        //Step 2 read byte

        String st = new String("see if it can write");
        bufWriter.append(enctext);
        bufWriter.close();


        //Step 1 send length
        output.writeInt(st.length());
        //Step 2 send length
        output.writeBytes(st); // UTF is a string encoding
        //  output.writeUTF(data);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Connection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Connection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Connection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Connection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (EOFException e) {
        System.out.println("EOF:" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO:" + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {/*close failed*/

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The server does the following:

```
decrypt(input, new FileOutputStream("cleartext-reversed.txt"));
```

which reads everything from the input stream, decrypts it, and writes the result to the text file and closes the input stream.

Then right after, you're trying to do

```
int nb = input.read();
...
input.readChar()
```

which thus tries to read again from the input stream, that has just been read completely and closed.

Note: the diagnostic would be much easier if, instead of hiding the exception behind

```
System.out.println("EOF:" + e.getMessage());
```

you did

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

which would tell you what exception it is, and where it happens.

Comment: thanks for the help, however I stil can't get this to work. Any suggestions as to how I can verify that the encrypted text file is actually getting to the server? I have taken out the other attempts to read from the stream after the decrypt() call and I'm still left with an empty text file.